# Swift Error : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview, exc-bad-instruction

I am developing a web view application with Swift programming language.

I made a control on the URL because if it's a URL of Youtube,Facebook or something else external to the primary website, I want to open the URL in Safari. Until here everything ok.

The problem is when I click on a link (is a simple link that should open in Safari) the application crash with this error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0) on the "*" line.

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    *let stringaURL = try! String(contentsOf: request.url!)*

    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked{
        if((stringaURL.range(of:"www.collegiodeirettori.net/palio/")) != nil ){
            print(stringaURL)

        }
        else{

                UIApplication.shared.openURL(request.url!)
                return false;
        }


}
         return true;
}
```

Some advice to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to unwrap the request to make sure there's a valid URLRequest in `request`

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry but I'm not very expert with swift :/   

The question that I keep myself is: why link with certain works while others do not and the application crash?

Comment: look up 'swift optional unwrapping'